# Phonegap caching JSON?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am testing a simple script for a larger solution; Im retrieving information from an external JSON file and displaying it within a PhoneGap app. The script works as needed, except when I change the content (not the structure) of the external JSON file. In fact I can even remove the JSON file from the server and the script still displays the original JSON content. Apparently there is something caching somewhere. Is there a way to disable such?

BTW Im running this on a local device via USB debugging not an emulator.

Here is the code (the console log is present for earlier debugging via the browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});      

$.getJSON( "http://www.serverxyz.com/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
</script>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the JSON content:

```
{
  "Goal One": "Activity One Completed",
  "Goal Two": "Activity Two Completed",
  "Goal Three": "Activity Three Completed",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can use the cache:false for this. Hope someone finds this helpful.